# Can't read the whole file into a String in Java

Tags: java, java-io

Once again

Hello,

retrying my question

I have downloaded a file from the internet, namely this one:

[jquery.js](http://web.archive.org/web/20160406061922js_/http://index.hu/assets/js/jquery.js)

It is 94159 bytes, and checking it, everything seems fine. Now I would like to read this file into a String, manipulate it, then save it. After reading the file, I print it to the console and it seems like it didn't read the whole file(parts from the end are missing).
After saving it is only 91000 bytes.

I have tried different reading methods, so I don't think it is the problem, eg:

```
String fileTo = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileFullPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(same result with scanner,stream)

Probably something to do with the file itself. The file on my mac is in utf-8, maybe originally it wasn't? I really have no idea what the cause could be. 
Thanks for help.

Edit:

This is how I downloaded it:

```
try (InputStream fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(
            conn.getInputStream());
         OutputStream fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(
                 new FileOutputStream(fileFullPath)))
    {
        int readByte;
        while ((readByte = fileReader.read()) != -1)
        {
            fileWriter.write(readByte);
        }
```

Comment: How do you save the file? My guess is that, the 3 lines of code in this file are so long, that your console truncates them.

Comment: Save like this: try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileFullPath))) {
                out.print(fileTo);
            }

Comment: When you convert to a String, you may get less characters than you have bytes as you might have multi-byte characters.

Comment: If you are trying to copy a file, I suggest you read as bytes and copy say 8192 bytes at a time.  No need to read as String and possibly message the character encoding.  I suspect you are not writing the same character encoding as you read, meaning the number of bytes can be different.

Comment: This uses your default encoding instead of the original one. Use `try (Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            out.write(fileTo);
        }`

Comment: Seems like if I read file into byte array, the byte array's size is also smaller than the file size

Answer (score 0):

You told that you are getting the file from `Internet`.

So you could set encoding character-set from response HTTP header `Content-Type` which look like:

```
Content-Type: text/html,text/html;charset='UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

After downloading to my machine, `ls -l jquery.js` prints `-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 94159 Apr  9 12:25 jquery.js`, which confirms the file size is 94159 bytes.

However, at position 14566 (inside `.test(" ")`, there is a unicode sequence (0xC2, 0xA0), which is the UTF-8 unicode "nonbreaking space" (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

When I run the following program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class FileSize {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final String fileFullPath = "jquery.js";
            String fileTo = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileFullPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println( fileTo.length() );
        } catch (IOException error) {

        }
    }
}
```

it prints `94158`.  The difference of one byte is explained by the "UTF-8" encoding, but it cannot explain the 91000 bytes.  The explanation must be somewhere else.

Comment: Dunno, I added my download method, maybe that is the one at fault.

Comment: Anyway weird, I do the same as you, so I should have the same result. I am on OS X if that matters.

Answer (score -1):

`String` can't handle such big files well. Use `StringBuilder` instead:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileFullPath))
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(bytes);
```

Comment: String and StringBuilder can handle just over 2 billion characters.